# When exporting contacts using custom selected fields, results in "Undefined Index ...Mapping.php Line 622"

Tags: contacts, php, export

When trying to export a list of Contacts selecting a previously defined set of Export Fields, system throws this error:"Notice: Undefined index: in /home/.../Core/BAO/Mapping.php on line 622"

When exporting using primary fields, the export is successful.

What is the issue with Mapping.php?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, albeit a minor one because of the simple workaround.

In PHP (the language most of CiviCRM is written in), there are various levels of problem: notice, warning, error, etc.  A notice generally means, "This software's code has something ambiguous but not *wrong* about it.  We're going to infer what the code's author meant to do, but they may want to make it explicit."

Good software strives to be notice-free, and CiviCRM is mostly notice-free.  You've discovered an exception - though you haven't noted your CiviCRM version, so it's quite possible this is already fixed.

The reason this is less important than many other bugs is that notices should be *suppressed* on a live instance of CiviCRM - they should only really pop up if you're a developer.  So the fix for this is to change your PHP settings to hide notices.  This issue should go away after that.  There's a few ways to disable notices; this Stack Exchange answer outlines them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices

Answer (score 0):

I have found a corrupted line entry in the database table civicrm_mapping. Went to Administer >> System Settings >> Import/Export mappings and tried to delete the line entry, but the system hung there without completing the step.

DROPPED the tables CIVICRM_MAPPING, CIVICRM_MAPPING_FIELD, and CIVICRM_SAVED_SEARCH and recreated them from a backup copy (blank tables), but this still hasn't fixed the error.

When executing a contacts search and using "Select fields for export":
[image: Screenshot of selection]

I get this error:

**Notice: Undefined index: in .../joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Mapping.php on line 622**

Any ideas??

Comment: This seems like additional info to supplement the original question, and not an answer.  Please edit the original question to include this info and delete this answer?  Thanks!